# keep selected dropdown value on python

Tags: google-app-engine, drop-down-menu, python-2.7

I use google app engine with python. I have on html a drop down menu, but each time I submit the form, the dropdown go back to the first option. I found tutorials to do this only with php. Is therey any way to do this with python?

```
        {% for ctr in countries %}
          {% if ctr == sele_country %}
              <option selected="selected">ctr</option>
          {% else %}
              <option>ctr</option>
          {%endif%}
        {%endfor%}
```

**Update: SOLVED**

I find the solution. The right code is

```
{% for ctr in countries %}
          {% if ctr == sele_country %}
              <option selected="selected">{{ctr}}</option>
          {% else %}
              <option>{{ctr}}</option>
          {%endif%}
        {%endfor%}
```

I don't know why, but inside the loop, I need to add again the bruckets on ctr.

Comment: You need to pass the submitted value to the form that submits it. or read it if it's already set.

Comment: I think you are a bit confused.. you should pass these values not in the *.html files but in the Python code.. check the getting started from Google on how they are passing parameters to Jinja2 templates from Python.

Comment: Totally missed that part.. probably I was drunk few moments ago.. of course.. I updated my answer

Comment: And just to keep it clear.. you can delete all your updates and leave the initial code as it was.. because actually the problem is there.. so for future reference it will make more sense, without all these updates.. It makes the question unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't enclose the `selected_value` in curly brackets and you'll be fine:

```
{% for value in values %}
  {% if value == selected_value %}
     <option selected>{{value}}</option>
  {% else %}
     <option>{{value}}</option>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The missed quote was a typo here. Thank you. But how I will pass parameters from back-end if I don't use the curly brackets? This is how python pass parameters on html.

Comment: @Tasos compare my code to yours to see exactly what's the difference between them. It's on line 2. The if statement is already in curly brackets.

Comment: @Tasos I also updated the `in` missed that part.. now it should be ok.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't know that inside a bracket, you don't need to add them again. I tried it without and I don't have an error but my dropdown is empty.

Comment: @Tasos then most likely something is wrong with your `values` and the `selected_value` variables.. You could also give us the snippet of code where you are actually setting them and how do you pass them to the template.